# Show that the recursive sequence is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

$$a_1 = 1$$

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2} \left(a_n+\frac{2}{a_n}\right) \ge \sqrt{a_n \cdot\frac{2}{a_n}} = \sqrt{2}$$

I don't understand what happens at the $\ge$ step. Are there any middle steps which can help me understand why is that so?

Comment: Have you heard of the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)?

Comment: For $x,y\geq 0$, $ x+y-2\sqrt{xy}=(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\geq 0$

Comment: Generally for positive numbers $a,b$, one has $\dfrac{a+b} 2 \ge \sqrt{ab\,{}}$. i.e. the arithmetic mean is bigger than the geometric mean. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality of arithmetic and geometric means states that if $a,b$ are non-negative numbers then $\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$.

This example uses $a = a_n$ and $b = \frac{2}{a_n}$